# Python - Searching JSON

Tags: python, json

I have JSON output as follows:

```
{
"service": [{
    "name": ["Production"],
    "id": ["256212"]
}, {
    "name": ["Non-Production"],
    "id": ["256213"]
}]
}
```

I wish to find all ID's where the pair contains "Non-Production" as a name.

I was thinking along the lines of running a loop to check, something like this:

```
data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(URL))


for key, value in data.iteritems():

if "Non-Production" in key[value]: print key[value]
```

However, I can't seem to get the name and ID from the "service" tree, it returns:

```
   if "Non-Production" in key[value]: print key[value]
   TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Assumptions:

- The JSON is in a fixed format, this can't be changed
- I do not have root access, and unable to install any additional packages

Essentially the goal is to obtain a list of ID's of non production "services" in the most optimal way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
data = {
    "service": [
        {"name": ["Production"],
         "id": ["256212"]
        },
        {"name": ["Non-Production"],
         "id": ["256213"]}
    ]
}

for item in data["service"]:
    if "Non-Production" in item["name"]:
        print(item["id"])
```

Comment: `for item in data["service"]:`
`KeyError: 'service'`

Comment: Then you should `print(data)` to see how the returned structure looks like. Apparently it's different from the sample you posted...

Comment: Hmm, yes it seems to be printing slightly differently:
`{
 u 'stat': u 'ok', u 'service': [{
  u 'name': [u 'Production'],
  u 'id': [u '256212']
 }]
}`
What are the u's?

Comment: You have to use .get('key', defaultvalue)

Comment: @e-nouri - is this on `data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(URL)).get('key', defaultvalue)`?

Comment: `data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(URL))` then you do like so `data.get('service', {})`

Answer (score 0):

Whatever I see `JSON` I think about functionnal programming ! Anyone else ?!
I think it is a better idea if you use function like concat or flat, filter and reduce, etc.

Egg one liner:

```
[s.get('id', [0])[0] for s in filter(lambda srv : "Non-Production" not in srv.get('name', []), data.get('service', {}))]
```

EDIT:

I updated the code, even if `data = {}`, the result will be `[]` an empty id list.