# How do you access JSON subdata with Python

Tags: python

I'm working with some JSON data with Python. Basically I have the following JSON data

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "name": "John Doe",
            "prefix": "[Test Account]",
            "rank": "10"
        },
        {
            "name": "Jane Doe",
            "prefix": "[Test Account]",
            "rank": "10"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have a loop that successfully loops through the users in Python.

```
for x in data["users"]:
    if username == data["users"]["name"]:
        print("true")
```

I want to get just the `name` value. In JS you'd do it like this

```
data.users[x].name
```

But how do you do it in Python. I've tried stuff like

```
data["users"][x]["name"]
```

and

```
data["users"[x]]["name"]
```

Both throw errors. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Searching JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38347855/python-searching-json)

Comment: `for x in data["users"]:
    print( x["name"] )`

Comment: `x` is going to be a `dict`, use `x['name']`, note this has nothing to do with JSON, really

Comment: @Rakesh Thanks, it worked

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Oh, I thought that  because it was JSON data the JSON tag would work. I'll remove it.

Comment: I mean this may seem like a pedantic point, but I think it's important. JSON is a text-based serialization format. Once you deserialize it you are not working with JSON.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
data = {
    "users": [
        {
            "name": "John Doe",
            "prefix": "[Test Account]",
            "rank": "10"
        },
        {
            "name": "Jane Doe",
            "prefix": "[Test Account]",
            "rank": "10"
        }
    ]
}
username = "John Doe"

for x in data["users"]:
    if username == x["name"]:
        print("true")
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried this quick example and it works:

```
import json
j = '{"u":[{"a":1},{"a":2},{"a":3}]}'
d=json.loads(j)
print(d["u"][1]["a"])
# output: 2
```

---

what's your error-message when you did:

```
data["users"][x]["name"]
```

?

Comment: My error message was `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict`

Comment: strange. It works for me, when I try `data["users"][1]["name"]`. You sure your `x` was an int? (in python types are a little stricter than in JS)

Comment: Well, when I replaced it with a `1` from a `x` it worked.

Answer (score 1):

In above answer, you just add a list and get all names.

```
data = {
    "users": [
        {
            "name": "John Doe",
            "prefix": "[Test Account]",
            "rank": "10"
        },
        {
            "name": "Jane Doe",
            "prefix": "[Test Account]",
            "rank": "10"
        }
    ]
}
username = "John Doe"
names = []
for x in data["users"]:
    names.append(x["name"])


>>names
['John Doe', 'Jane Doe']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {
   "users": [
      {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "prefix": "[Test Account]",
        "rank": "10"
      },
      {
        "name": "Jane Doe",
        "prefix": "[Test Account]",
        "rank": "10"
      }
  ]
}

for x in data['users']:
  print(x['name'])
```